# Como colocar uma soma nessa minha formula JS?

Tags: javascript, formulário

Como eu coloco uma formula que some um valor a um grupo de CEP no meu formulário de pedido?

Exemplo: nos ceps 22750-670, 22750-700 e 22750-750 será somado o valor de R$ 4,00 (4.00) ao total do pedido.

O arquivo que eu é responsável pelos cálculo do meu formulário é form.js, abaixo tenho ele completo:

```
var str = "";
var id = "";
var sub = 0.00;
var total = 0.00;
var qcount = 0;
var scount = 0;
var opc = 0;

var options = "";
for (i=1; i<21; i++){
    options += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>";
}

$( document ).ready(function() {

$( "div div select" ).html(options); 
$( "div div :text" ).attr("value","1");
$( "#btemporio" ).click(function() {
  $( "#emporio" ).css("display","block");
});
$( "#mudaopcao" ).click(function() {
  location.reload(true);
});
    function alerta(txt){
        $( "div#alerta" ).html( txt ).show( 0 ).delay( 2500 ).fadeOut( 500 );
    }
function atencao(txt){
        $( "div#atencao" ).html( txt ).show( 0 ).delay( 2500 ).fadeOut( 500 );
    }
function mens(){
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getDate() + "|" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "|" + d.getFullYear() + " - " + d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes();

    $( "div#quentes :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
          str = str + $(this).parent().children("strong").text();
          if (opc == 4){
              var sel = $(this).parent().children("span").children("select").val();
              str = str + ": R$ " + $(this).val().replace(".", ",") + " x " + sel + " = R$ " + (($(this).val() * sel).toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",");
          }
          str = str + "<br>";
    })
    $('input[name=quentes]').val(str);
    str = "";

    $( "div#saladas :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
          str = str + $(this).parent().children("strong").text();
          if (opc == 4){
              var sel = $(this).parent().children("span").children("select").val();
              str = str + ": R$ " + $(this).val().replace(".", ",") + " x " + sel + " = R$ " + (($(this).val() * sel).toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",");
          }
          str = str + "<br>";
    })
    $('input[name=saladas]').val(str);
    str = "";

    $( "div#sobremesas :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
          var sel = $(this).parent().children("select").val();
          str = str + $(this).parent().children("strong").text() + ": R$ " + $(this).val().replace(".", ",") + " x " + sel + " = R$ " + (($(this).val() * sel).toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",") + "<br>";
    })
    $('input[name=sobremesas]').val(str);
    str = "";

    $( "div#sucos :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
          var sel = $(this).parent().children("select").val();
          var val = $(this).parent().children("input:radio:checked").val();
          str = str + $(this).parent().children("strong").text() + " - " + $(this).parent().children("input:radio:checked").attr("l") + ": R$ " + val.replace(".", ",") + " x " + sel + " = R$ " + (val * sel).toFixed(2).replace(".", ",") + "<br>";
    })
    $('input[name=sucos]').val(str);
    str = "";

    $( "div#bebidas :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
          var sel = $(this).parent().children("select").val();
          str = str + $(this).parent().children("strong").text() + ": R$ " + $(this).val().replace(".", ",") + " x " + sel + " = R$ " + (($(this).val() * sel).toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",") + "<br>";
    })
    $('input[name=bebidas]').val(str);
    str = "";

    $( "div#sopas :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
          var sel = $(this).parent().children("select").val();
          str = str + $(this).parent().children("strong").text() + ": R$ " + $(this).val().replace(".", ",") + " x " + sel + " = R$ " + (($(this).val() * sel).toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",") + "<br>";
    })
    $('input[name=sopas]').val(str);
    str = "";

    $( "div#emporio :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
          var sel = $(this).parent().children("select").val();
          str = str + $(this).parent().children("strong").text() + ": R$ " + $(this).val().replace(".", ",") + " x " + sel + " = R$ " + (($(this).val() * sel).toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",") + "<br>";
    })
    $('input[name=emporio]').val(str);
    str = "";

    str = String(total.toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",");
    $('input[name=mtotal]').val(str);
    str = "";

    if(opc==1){
        $('input[name=op]').val("3 Quentes e 3 Saladas");
    }else if(opc==2){
        $('input[name=op]').val("4 Quentes e 4 Saladas");
    }else if(opc==3){
        $('input[name=op]').val("5 Quentes e 5 Saladas");
    }else{
        $('input[name=op]').val("");
    }

    if(opc==0){
        $('input[name=nop]').val("");       
    } else {
        str = "<strong>Opção " + opc + ": </strong>";
        $('input[name=nop]').val(str);
        str = "";
    }

    $('input[name=data]').val(n);
}

  $("div#quentes :checkbox").click(function(){
      if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
          qcount++;
          if (opc == 1){
              if (qcount == 4){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", false );
                  atencao("Você só pode escolher 3 pratos quentes, para mais escolha outra opção");
                  qcount = 3;
              }
              if (qcount == 1){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 2 pratos quentes");

              }
              if (qcount == 2){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 1 prato quente");

              }
          } else if (opc == 2){
              if (qcount == 5){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", false );
                  atencao("Você só pode escolher 4 pratos quentes, para mais escolha outra opção");
                  qcount = 4;
              }
               if (qcount == 1){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 3 pratos quentes");

              }
              if (qcount == 2){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 2 pratos quentes");

              }
               if (qcount == 3){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 1 prato quente");

              }
          } else if (opc == 3){
              if (qcount == 6){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", false );
                  atencao("Você só pode escolher 5 pratos quentes, para mais escolha outra opção");
                  qcount = 5;
              }
                if (qcount == 1){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 4 pratos quentes");

              }
              if (qcount == 2){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 3 pratos quentes");

              }
               if (qcount == 3){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 2 pratos quentes");

              }
               if (qcount == 4){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 1 prato quente");

              }
          }
      } else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
          qcount--;
      }
  })

  $("div#saladas :checkbox").click(function(){
      if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
          scount++;
          if (opc == 1){
              if (scount == 4){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", false );
                  atencao("Você só pode escolher 3 saladas, para mais escolha outra opção");
                  scount = 3;
              }
              if (scount == 1){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 2 saladas");
              }
              if (scount == 2){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 1 salada");
              }

          } else if (opc == 2){
              if (scount == 5){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", false );
                  atencao("Você só pode escolher 4 saladas, para mais escolha outra opção");
                  scount = 4;
              }
               if (scount == 1){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 3 saladas");
              }
              if (scount == 2){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 2 saladas");
              }
              if (scount == 3){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 1 salada");
              }

          } else if (opc == 3){
              if (scount == 6){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", false );
                  atencao("Você só pode escolher 5 saladas, para mais escolha outra opção");
                  scount = 5;
              }
              if (scount == 1){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 4 saladas");
              }
              if (scount == 2){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 3 saladas");
              }
              if (scount == 3){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 2 saladas");
              }
              if (scount == 4){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 1 salada");
              }
          }
      } else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
          scount--;
      }
  })

  $( ":input" ).click(function() {
  total = 0;
  sub = 0;

  if ($( "div#opcoes input:radio:checked" ).length > 0) {
    $( "#mudaopcao, #titulo2, div#quentes :checkbox, div#saladas :checkbox" ).css("display","inline-block");
    sub += $( "div#opcoes input:radio:checked" ).val() * 1;
    if ($( "div#opcoes input:radio:checked" ).attr("op") == 1){
        opc = 1;
        $( "#op2,#op3,#op4,div#quentes span" ).css("display","none");
    } else if ($( "div#opcoes input:radio:checked" ).attr("op") == 2){
        opc = 2;
        $( "#op1,#op3,#op4,div#quentes span" ).css("display","none");
    } else if ($( "div#opcoes input:radio:checked" ).attr("op") == 3){
        opc = 3;
        $( "#op1,#op2,#op4,div#quentes span" ).css("display","none");
    } else if ($( "div#opcoes input:radio:checked" ).attr("op") == 4){
        opc = 4;
        $( "#op1,#op2,#op3,div#quentes span" ).css("display","none");
        $("div#quentes span, div#saladas span").css("display","inline-block");
        $( "div#quentes :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
            sub += $( this ).val() * $( this ).parent().find("select").val();
        }) //each quentes
        $( "div#saladas :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
            sub += $( this ).val() * $( this ).parent().find("select").val();
        }) //each saladas
    }
  }

    $( "div#sobremesas :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
        sub += $( this ).val() * $( this ).parent().children( "select" ).val();
    }) //each sobremesas

    $( "div#sucos :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
        sub += $( this ).parent().children( ":radio:checked" ).val() * $( this ).parent().children( "select" ).val();
    }) //each sucos

    $( "div#bebidas :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
        sub += $( this ).val() * $( this ).parent().children( "select" ).val();
    }) //each bebidas

    $( "div#sopas :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
        sub += $( this ).val() * $( this ).parent().children( "select" ).val();
    }) //each sopas

    $( "div#emporio :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
        sub += $( this ).val() * $( this ).parent().children( "select" ).val();
    }) //each emporio

    total += sub;

    $( "div#total" ).html( "Valor total da sua<br>encomenda: R$ " + String(total.toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",") );
    $( "div#total" ).css("display", "block");
    $( "#total2" ).html( "R$ " + String(total.toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",") );
  }) //click
  $( "#total2" ).html( "R$ " + String(total.toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",") );


  $( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
     if (opc == 4 && (qcount + scount)<6){
        event.preventDefault();
        alerta("Você deve escolher, no mínimo, 6 itens, entre os pratos quentes e saladas");
        return false;
    } else if (total < 17.90){
        event.preventDefault();
        alerta("O valor mínimo do pedido é R$ 17,90");
        return false;
    } else if ($("#nome").val()=="" || $("#endereco").val()=="" || $("#email").val()=="" || $("#cep").val()=="" || $("#telefone").val()==""){
        event.preventDefault();
        alerta("Todos os campos de informação são obrigatórios");
        return false;
    }
    mens();
  }); //form

}); // doc ready
```

Acredito que é nesse arquivo que teremos que colocar a formula!!
Sou leigo, o que eu consegui montar até agora foi através da ajuda desse site e de alguns fóruns, mas acredito que essa formula terá que ler sempre esse `INPUT` para poder colocar a soma ou não né?

```
<td>CEP:</td>
<td><input id="cep" name="cep" type="text" size="60" value="<? echo $cep ?>"></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embaixo da linha `total += sub;` você deve colocar um if, para verificar qual o CEP e se deverá incrementar o valor. Ex:
Você deve criar um `span` com o id `idTaxa` ou outro para que o javascript possa mostrar posteriormente.

```
<span id="idTaxa" />

total += sub;
var taxa = 0;
//aqui eu pego o cep
var cep = document.getElementById("cep").value;
//verifica se deve incrementar ou não
if(cep == "22750-670" || cep == "22750-700" || cep == "22750-750"){
    //se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 4 no valor final
    taxa = 4;
}if(...){
    //segundo if caso tenha para taxa de 6 reais
    taxa = 6;
}

total += taxa;

if(taxa != 0){
    //caso a taxa seja diferente de 0, mostra ao usuário
    document.getElementById('idTaxa').innerHTML = "Custo adicional: R$" + taxa;
}
```

Comment: Deu certinho, muito obrigado!! Sem querer abusar, tem como eu criar um echo onde o PHP vai puxar a informação de quanto é essa taxa? A soma já é feita automaticamente, ficou show, mas queria mostrar no final do formulário quanto ele está pagando de taxa de entrega. Vou criar outros if para diferentes valores de taxa de entrega, CEPs.

Comment: Editei a resposta.  Caso esteja certa, favor, marcar como resposta certa para que os outros usuários possam saber que sua pergunta já foi respondida

Comment: Oi Julyano, muito obrigado mais uma vez. Mas agora, essa formula não deu certo, não carrega os valores. Na anterior carregava.

Comment: Fiz vários testes, e descobrir que a parte que faz com que não funcione é justamente essa: `if(taxa != 0){
    //caso a taxa seja diferente de 0, mostra ao usuário
    doccument.getElementById('idTaxa').innerHTML = "Custo adicional: R$" + taxa;
}` tirando essa parte, tudo funciona, mas essa parte seria para aparecer a taxa no formulário? Na parte span? Eu criei a área no formulário.

Comment: Achei o erro, era na digitação, está doccment.get... o certo é document com apenas um C. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!!!